# IdentityServer4 response format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is there a way in IdentityServer4 to change the format of the output json?

For example:
`access_token` to `accessToken`

Comment: Why do you need such a requirement? If I understand the whole problem, maybe I can help by a workaround.

Comment: I need it, because the architect asked me to be in that format. Like this [link](https://imgur.com/aqV8eMs)

Comment: You can use a controller action which can behave like a proxy between the client and identity server. But only "resource owner password flow" can be implemented this way without problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The responses are defined as a part of the oidc spec, so they cannot be changed.

Comment: I supposed it, but it's the requirement that I have